# Notifier doesn't stop parallel loops on error

Tags: labview

I am trying to create a simple VI in LabVIEW 2020 SP1 that stops two parallel loops when a stop button is pressed, or either loop encounters an error. I've used notifiers thus far and have the stop button functionality working, but when I inject an error to check I get the same behaviour with errors, the program continues running instead of stopping.

[image: block diagram]

My understanding is that when the "Inject Error" button is pressed, the status flag of the error cluster in the second loop becomes true, which the notifier then sends as a boolean notification to both loops. Upon receiving a notification, each loop - which stops on true - terminates. My debugging attempts have shown that the second loop notifier is being called, but there is no response in either 'Wait for Notification'.

I feel like I'm missing something basic here. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the '[send notification](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview-api-ref/page/functions/send-notification.html)' function doesn't function when the error-in is true. This is [normal behaviour for a lot of VIs](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/using-the-standard-functionality-for-error-in-parameters.html). In this case you want to disconnect the error in from the set notifier.
Other tip, you can [directly wire the error into the case structure selector](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/handling-errors-using-case-structures.html), no need to break out the 'status' bit.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise VIs are bypassed when an error is fed into them. Also, I figured you could use error wires without exposing the status, but the unexpected behaviour made me doubt myself - so thanks for the clarification there.

Comment: Waiting Queue and Notifier VIs will release immediately (with an error) when the reference they are listening on is released, so generally the most convenient way to manage multiple loops is a [code pattern I call scuttling](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/handling-while-loop-in-subvi/m-p/1117933/highlight/true#M493583), in which release of the reference is used to terminate loops. This lets you write code without timeouts that will exit immediately on demand.